# Problems With Using String.Replace to Modify the Output of the XML Serializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am generating an xml file. I noticed in the file it has a tag I do not want. I am generating the xml file from the xmlSerializer object and what its doing is handling a Property on my object wrong...The proerty on my object lloks like this...

```
public List<ProductVarient> Varients { get; set; }
```

So when I serialize it, I get a structure like this

```
<Varients>
  <ProductVarient>
     <Name>Nick</Name>
     ......
```

I want just

```
  <AnotherProp>
     <Stuff>toys</Stuff>
  </AnotherProp>
  <ProductVarient>
     <Name>Nick</Name>
  </ProductVarient>
  <ProductVarient>
     <Name>Jeff</Name>
  </ProductVarient>
....
```

So instead of trying to workaround the xmlserializer, I went with a super hack and wrote this code

```
 string s = File.ReadAllText(path);
    s.Replace("<Varients>", "");
    s.Replace("</Varients>", "");

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("");
        writer.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

2 Questions

-The code I wrote wont Replace  with "", it doesnt throw an exception but it doesnt work either, im not sure why?
-Is there a quick better way to accomplish my problem.

Comment: you have to return value from string.Replace method

Comment: Why don't you solve the original problem of generating xml the right way? Use XMLIgnoreAttribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx  Alternatively I'd modify the stream in memory than reading from the file to replace.

Comment: "Varient" should be spelled "Variant" (this isn't why your code isn't working though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to "work around" the XmlSerializer, you should learn to use it properly.

Try placing `[XmlElement]` on  your property:

```
[XmlElement]
public List<ProductVarient> Varients { get; set; }
```

Alternatively, you can try [XmlArray] and [XmlArrayItem] attributes. You haven't shown a good example of the XML you want (what do you want if there are multiple items in the list?), so I can't tell you which you should use.

Comment: I populate the Varients list by adding ProductVarients to it I want it to return the multiple items in the list without creating a Varients node... It does it but thinks its <Varients> ---><ProductVarient> and I just want <ProductVarient>. I do not have any [XmlElement] attributes on any of my propeties as of now.

Comment: @Nick: try placing such an attribute there and see how it changes the resulting XML. Also, please show an example of the XML you would want to see if there were two `ProductVarient` instances in the list.

Comment: @Nick: glad to help. Perhaps you could update your question to show the resulting XML.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
s = s.Replace("<Varients>", "");
s = s.Replace("</Varients>", "");
```

`String` is immutable, and methods like `Replace` *return* their result instead of mutating the receiver.

**UPDATE:** But, a better solution, as stated by [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382570/problems-with-string-replace/5382659#5382659), is to use the `XmlSerializer` to achieve what you want:

```
[XmlElement("ProductVarient")]
public List<ProductVarient> Varients { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad hack and should be sent to it's room, but to answer your question:

```
 string s = File.ReadAllText(path);
    s = s.Replace("<Varients>", "");
    s = s.Replace("</Varients>", "");

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("");
        writer.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Replace returns a modified string, just using the extension doesn't do anything unless the result is returned.